# Modifying the current fact that fires a rule

Tags: rule, clips

Say I have defined a template and some facts as shown below:

```
(deftemplate student
    (slot name (type SYMBOL) (default ?NONE))
    (slot grade (type SYMBOL) (default C) (allowed-symbols A B C D))
    (slot graduated (type SYMBOL) (default no) (allowed-symbols yes no))
)

(deffacts insert-facts
    (student (name George) (grade A))
    (student (name Nick) (grade C))
    (student (name Bob))
    (student (name Mary) (grade B))
)
```

Say that I want to create a rule that checks the grade of each student and
sets the corresponding graduated variable to the symbol 'yes'. How could I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a slightly less verbose version of the rule you came up with to solve your problem:

```
CLIPS> 
(deftemplate student
    (slot name (type SYMBOL) (default ?NONE))
    (slot grade (type SYMBOL) (default C) (allowed-symbols A B C D))
    (slot graduated (type SYMBOL) (default no) (allowed-symbols yes no)))
CLIPS> 
(deffacts insert-facts
    (student (name George) (grade A))
    (student (name Nick) (grade C))
    (student (name Bob))
    (student (name Mary) (grade B)))
CLIPS> 
(defrule rule-1
   ?s <- (student (grade A|B) (name ?n) (graduated ~yes))
   =>
   (modify ?s (graduated yes))
   (printout t "Congratulations " ?n "!" crlf))
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (run)
Congratulations Mary!
Congratulations George!
CLIPS>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. I leave it here in case someone else needs it.

I have created the rule in the following way

```
(defrule rule-1
    ?s <- (student (grade ?g&A|B) (name ?n) (graduated ?gr) (classified ?c&no))
=>
    (retract ?s)
    (assert (student (name ?n)(grade ?g) (graduated yes) (classified yes)))
    (printout t "Congratulations " ?n "!" crlf)
)
```

And have modified the student template in the following way, in order to prevent the program from falling into an infinite loop.

```
(deftemplate student
    (slot name (type SYMBOL) (default ?NONE))
    (slot grade (type SYMBOL) (default C) (allowed-symbols A B C D))
    (slot graduated (type SYMBOL) (default no) (allowed-symbols yes no))
    (slot classified (type SYMBOL) (default no) (allowed-symbols yes no))
)
```